# Cross platform solution for getting current login name in Python

Tags: python, authentication

I'm looking for a cross platform solution for getting current login/username in Python.

I was surprised that `os.getlogin()` is only supported under Unix and even there is not necessarily returning what you would expect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`getpass.getuser()`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser) is your friend.

Comment: +1 that's a nifty module

Comment: getpass is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use:

```
import os
username = getattr(os, "getlogin", None)
if not username:
    for var in ['USER', 'USERNAME','LOGNAME']:
        if  var in os.environ:
            username = os.environ[var]
print("username: %s" % (username))
```

Comment: You're basically reinventing the `getpass` wheel.